# How to store text from multiple buttons in one variable in android development?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to store the text on a button in a variable.

I refered [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383512/how-to-store-button-text-of-buttons-in-a-variable-android-calculator-project) article but it defines for "One variable for one button".My app is going to have around 80-90 buttons. How can I store data from any of these buttons in a single variable and use that common variable for further operations?

Example -

I have buttons -  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

How can I initialise them to a single button (the `btn = (Button) findViewById`... thing) in java and thus get their text in one single variable? Coz i cant define 90 buttons separately in java!!

How can i do this?

Here is the code of what ive done..(A completely supid or inefficient way)-

What it basically does is - out of 12 buttons,whichever is pressed,concatinates it with a string.
like if 1 is pressed the string will be 01 after that if 10 is pressed, the string will become 0110 and so on...

```
public class FEa extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12;
    TextView tvDisp;
    String acc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fea);
        initialise();
    }

    private void initialise()
    {
        b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn4);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn5);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn6);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn7);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn8);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn9);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
        b10 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn10);
        b10.setOnClickListener(this);
        b11 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn11);
        b11.setOnClickListener(this);
        b12 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Btn12);
        b12.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvDisp=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtViewDisplay);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.Btn1:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "01";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            else
            {
                acc=acc + "0"+1;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }

            break;
        case R.id.Btn2:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "02";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0"+2;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn3:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "03";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0"+3;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn4:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "04";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0"+4;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn5:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "05";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0"+5;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn6:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "06";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0"+6;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn7:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "07";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0"+7;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn8:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "08";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0"+8;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn9:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "09";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + "0" +9;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn10:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "10";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + 10;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn11:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "11";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + 11;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn12:

            if(acc == null)
            {
                acc = "12";
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);     
            }
            else
            {
                acc = acc + 12;
                tvDisp.setText("String Is:" + acc);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post some relevant code for more help

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ....edited and code added

Comment: So what you are asking is how to `getText()` from all of these buttons simply, is that correct??

Comment: @Nirmik : why you are not using android:tag="01" in xml layout for setting text to every button and then use ternary operator for getting default text  instead of making more line of code?

Comment: umm..could you give ne a snippet for better understanding? m new to android programming and dont know all the function or options that can be used...how do i use the ternary operator and all?

Comment: @Asok...yeah but in one single variable...not a new one for every button.

Comment: @Nirmik When you get a chance please improve you accept rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should have every button call the same onClick method, which you can set in xml for all buttons:

```
<Button android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

Then in your activity, you can accumulate your string very easily:

```
public class FEa extends Activity
{
   TextView tvDisp;
   String acc = "";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.fea);
       tvDisp = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtViewDisplay);
   }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        Button theButton = (Button)v;
        acc = acc + theButton.getText().toString();
        tvDisp.setText("String Is: " + acc);
    }

}
```

Comment: I should add the `android:onClick="onButtonClick"` line to all the buttons? Or add that whole snippet along with the existing buttons?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Or, if you don't want to define 80 buttons in XML, you can define one onClickListener that will do the same thing as this method and just write a loop to generate the number of buttons you need and assign the one onClickListener to it.

Comment: Sorry, you just made an edit. To respond directly to your question, yes, you do want to add that line to every button.

Comment: consider creating a style with and just applying that every button - this way if you change the style or want to refactor all will change from one place :)

Comment: That was THE simplest way I could do it!! thanx a lot!!

Comment: No problem! Also, I agree with mr fox that a style would certainly make this easier to reactor later. That was a smart idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use some view like a view group to contain your buttons. Then you just have to use getChildAt(int index) in a for() or while() to get each button in any list and get the text from them one after another.

I never tried it but i think that i could work.

Hopes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code but you could set the tags for all of the buttons (in xml) to "button" then try something like storing all of the text in a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> buttonTexts;
RelativeLayout mainLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.fea);
    buttonTexts = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);
    getTxtFromBtns();
    Log.i("HashMapValues", buttonTexts.toString());
}

public void getTxtFromBtns() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= mainLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
        String buttonChk = (String) view.getTag();
        if (buttonChk.equals("button")) {
            Button newBtn = (Button) view;
            String buttonText = (String) newBtn.getText();
            buttonTexts.put(view.getId(), buttonText);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could retrieve the text simply by

```
String myButton = buttonTexts.get(R.id.Btn1);
```